# WPF memory leak and collapsed comboboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a .net 4.0 wpf application which has an expander and inside the expander, I have 2 combo boxes. The lifetime of the expander view and the view model are infinite (i.e. as long as the app is alive).

The content of the combobox itemsource is tied to the current working copy of my object model.

I have an option to load or create a new object model which simply drops the old object model and points to the new one. In my view model(which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) I track the change and make sure that I create a brand new collection for itemsource.

What I noticed is that after creating a new object model when the expander is collapsed (hence the comboboxes are also collapsed) and I run ANTS memory profiler, I still have the comboboxes referencing to the old object model... and this prevent the garbage collector to get rid of the old object model.

I did put some breakpoints in my viewmodel for the itemssource property and the selected item and I can see that my codes does set them to a new values (according to the new object model) whenever the new object model is created and I can see that the comboboxes binding are calling my getter after I raise a property change on itemsource and selected item. However, ANTS still reports that the comboboxes are referencing the old object model. Then what is interesting is that if I expand the expander and my comboboxes become visible, ANTS reports that all references to the old object model are gone. What could explain this behaviour?

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableSitesA, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedSiteA}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>


ObservableCollection<Site> AvailableSitesA
    {
        get { return _availableSitesA; }

        private set
        {
            if (value != _availableSitesA)
            {
                _availableSitesA = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AvailableSitesA");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should not reinstatiate `ObservableCollection`s everytime. Instead, clear all its items and insert new ones. Thats precisely what an ObservableCollection is meant for. I mean, keep a single instance of the ObservableCollection and you will not have this leak.

Comment: I sould have mentioned that I do create an instance of AvailableSitesA (ObservableCollection) in the ctor and then use '.Clear()' when I create the new object model. I do '.Add(X)' to add the new items. I also tried to use a List<> instead of the ObservableCollection and set it to an empty list (as a clear) and set is to a new list when I create the new object model... I got the same result for both. The continue to point to old collection until I expand the expander.

Comment: Can you show code where your are modifying Observablecollection?

Comment: I am creating a simple project to demonstrate the issue; I will post it once I am done...

Comment: Still don't know exactly what was wrong but noticed that the problem is not reproducible using .net 4.5... only happens in .net 4.0